# Azure LUIS Chatbot not working when added security to it

Tags: azure-active-directory, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-authentication, azure-appservice

I have developed an Azure LUIS chatbot and it was working as expected. but while adding security to it in the Azure portal like
1- App Service Authentication set to **On**
2- Action to take when the request is not authenticated set to **Log in with Azure Active Directory**

is ended up working and getting the below error

{
"error": {
"code": "BotError",
"message": "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"
},
"httpStatusCode": 401
}

Any idea how to proceed for the same to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Has the issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set Azure AD authentication provider.

[image]

Please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings) to configure it.